# R "Error in draw.quad.venn, Impossible: produces negative area" despite numbers being correct

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I'm trying to generate a four way Venn diagram using draw.quad.venn in the VennDiagram package in R, but it keeps throwing up the error message:

```
ERROR [2019-05-14 11:28:24] Impossible: a7  <- n234 - a6 produces negative area
Error in draw.quad.venn(length(gene_lists[[1]]), length(gene_lists[[2]]),  : 
  Impossible: a7  <- n234 - a6 produces negative area
```

I'm using 4 different lists of genes as the input. calculate.overlap works fine, then I get the numbers by using the length(x) function over the overlap values, parsed as a list. I pass all of the overlap values, along with the appropriate total group sizes, to the draw.quad.venn function, but it keeps claiming that one of the groups is impossible because it generates a negative number.

I've checked the numbers manually and they clearly add up to the correct values. I've also tested the script on a random set of 20000 genes, generated using something similar to the script below, and it works fine i.e. generates a four way Venn diagram. There are no differences between the randomly generated gene lists and the ones I've curated from actual results files, apart from their sizes. A minimal working example can be seen below:

```
# working example that fails
# get vector of 10000 elements (representative of gene list)
values <- c(1:10000)
# generate 4 subsets by random sampling
list_1 <- sample(values, size = 5000, replace = FALSE)
list_2 <- sample(values, size = 4000, replace = FALSE)
list_3 <- sample(values, size = 3000, replace = FALSE)
list_4 <- sample(values, size = 2000, replace = FALSE)
# compile them in to a list
lists <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)
# find overlap between all possible combinations (11 plus 4 unique to each list = 15 total)
overlap <- calculate.overlap(lists)
# get the lengths of each list - these will be the numbers used for the Venn diagram
overlap_values <- lapply(overlap, function(x) length(x))
# rename overlap values (easier to identify which groups are intersecting)
names(overlap_values) <- c("n1234", "n123", "n124", "n134", "n234", "n12", "n13", "n14", "n23", "n24", "n34", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")
# generate the venn diagram
draw.quad.venn(length(lists[[1]]), length(lists[[2]]), length(lists[[3]]), length(lists[[4]]), overlap_values$n12,
               overlap_values$n13, overlap_values$n14, overlap_values$n23, overlap_values$n24, overlap_values$n34,
               overlap_values$n123, overlap_values$n124, overlap_values$n134, overlap_values$n234, overlap_values$n1234)
```

I expect a four way Venn diagram regardless of whether or not some groups are 0, they should still be there, but labelled as 0. This is what it should look like:

[image: Four way Venn diagram, with gene list sizes in each group]

I'm not sure if it's because I have 0 values in the real data i.e. certain groups where there is no overlap? Is there any way to force draw.quad.venn() to take any values? If not, is there another package that I can use to achieve the same results? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Test with other package, if it works, then something is wrong with the data, I prefer to use `eulerr`, see e.g.: `library(eulerr); f1 <- venn(list(a = 1:4, b = 1:16, c = 1:10, d = 8:20)); plot(f1)`. Also, it helps if you can make your data reproducible that results in error.

Comment: According to error this `n234 - a6` results in negative value, can you check what values you have `n234` and `a6` ?

Comment: It's difficult to replicate the error exactly without using the gene lists I have. As for the numbers, n234 is 0, and a6 (n1234) is 1. This just means that there are no genes that are ONLY found in groups 2, 3 and 4, but there is 1 gene found in all 4 groups. The individual areas should have no bearing on each other though. The total in each circle should add up to the size of each gene list, which they all do, I've added these to the picture.

Comment: Like mentioned, can't help if we can't get the same error. Suggest try using other packages, if it works, then maybe file an issue with the author.

Comment: I've added in a working example that simply uses the numbers 1:10000, which also throws this error, albeit for different groups. Could it be a problem with the package itself? I'll try to use the eulerr package on my data.

Answer (score 1):

So nothing I tried could solve the error with the draw.quad.venn in the VennDiagram package. There's something wrong with the way it's written. As long as all of the numbers in each of the 4 ellipses add up to the total number of elements in that particular list, the Venn diagram is valid. For some reason, VennDiagram will only accept data where fewer intersections lead to higher numbers e.g. the intersection of groups 1, 2 and 3 MUST be higher than the intersection of all 4 groups. This doesn't represent real world data. It's entirely possible for groups 1, 2 and 3 to not intersect at all, whilst all 4 groups do intersect. In a Venn diagram, all of the numbers are independent, and represent the total number of elements common at each intersection. They do not have to have any bearing on each other.

I had a look at the eulerr package, but actually found a very simple method of plotting the venn diagram using venn in gplots, as follows:

```
# simple 4 way Venn diagram using gplots
# get some mock data
values <- c(1:20000)
list_1 <- sample(values, size = 5000, replace = FALSE)
list_2 <- sample(values, size = 4000, replace = FALSE)
list_3 <- sample(values, size = 3000, replace = FALSE)
list_4 <- sample(values, size = 2000, replace = FALSE)
lists <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)
# name thec list (required for gplots)
names(lists) <- c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4")
# get the venn table
v.table <- venn(lists)
# show venn table
print(v.table)
# plot Venn diagram
plot(v.table)
```

I now consider the matter solved. Thank you zx8754 for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have had a look at the source code of the package. In case you are still interested in the reason for the error, there are two ways to send data to `venn.diagram`. One is the `nxxxx` (e. g., n134) form and the other is the `an` (e. g., a5) form. In the examples, `n134` means "which elements belong **at least** to groups 1, 3 and 4". On the other hand, `a5` means "which elements **only** belong to groups 1, 3 and 4". The relationship between both forms is really convoluted, for instance a6 corresponds to `n1234`. This means that `n134 = a5 + a6`.
The problem is that `calculate.overlap` gives the numbers in the `an` form, whereas by default `draw.quad.venn` expects numbers in the `nxxxx` form. To use the values from `calculate.overlap`, you can set `direct.area` to `true` and provide the result of `calculate.overlap` in the `area.vector` parameter. For instance,

```
tmp <- calculate.overlap(list(a=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 10), b=c(3, 4, 5, 6), c=c(4, 6, 7, 8, 9), d=c(4, 8, 1, 9)))
overlap_values <- lapply(tmp, function(x) length(x))
draw.quad.venn(area.vector = c(overlap_values$a1, overlap_values$a2, overlap_values$a3, overlap_values$a4, 
                               overlap_values$a5, overlap_values$a6, overlap_values$a7, overlap_values$a8, 
                               overlap_values$a9, overlap_values$a10, overlap_values$a11, overlap_values$a12, 
                               overlap_values$a13, overlap_values$a14, overlap_values$a15), direct.area = T, category = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

[image: vd2]

If you are interested in something simpler and more flexible, I made the `nVennR` package for this type of problems:

```
library(nVennR)
g1 <- c('AF029684', 'M28825', 'M32074', 'NM_000139', 'NM_000173', 'NM_000208', 'NM_000316', 'NM_000318', 'NM_000450', 'NM_000539', 'NM_000587', 'NM_000593', 'NM_000638', 'NM_000655', 'NM_000789', 'NM_000873', 'NM_000955', 'NM_000956', 'NM_000958', 'NM_000959', 'NM_001060', 'NM_001078', 'NM_001495', 'NM_001627', 'NM_001710', 'NM_001716')
g2 <- c('NM_001728', 'NM_001835', 'NM_001877', 'NM_001954', 'NM_001992', 'NM_002001', 'NM_002160', 'NM_002162', 'NM_002258', 'NM_002262', 'NM_002303', 'NM_002332', 'NM_002346', 'NM_002347', 'NM_002349', 'NM_002432', 'NM_002644', 'NM_002659', 'NM_002997', 'NM_003032', 'NM_003246', 'NM_003247', 'NM_003248', 'NM_003259', 'NM_003332', 'NM_003383', 'NM_003734', 'NM_003830', 'NM_003890', 'NM_004106', 'AF029684', 'M28825', 'M32074', 'NM_000139', 'NM_000173', 'NM_000208', 'NM_000316', 'NM_000318', 'NM_000450', 'NM_000539')
g3 <- c('NM_000655', 'NM_000789', 'NM_004107', 'NM_004119', 'NM_004332', 'NM_004334', 'NM_004335', 'NM_004441', 'NM_004444', 'NM_004488', 'NM_004828', 'NM_005214', 'NM_005242', 'NM_005475', 'NM_005561', 'NM_005565', 'AF029684', 'M28825', 'M32074', 'NM_005567', 'NM_003734', 'NM_003830', 'NM_003890', 'NM_004106', 'AF029684', 'NM_005582', 'NM_005711', 'NM_005816', 'NM_005849', 'NM_005959', 'NM_006138', 'NM_006288', 'NM_006378', 'NM_006500', 'NM_006770', 'NM_012070', 'NM_012329', 'NM_013269', 'NM_016155', 'NM_018965', 'NM_021950', 'S69200', 'U01351', 'U08839', 'U59302')
g4 <- c('NM_001728', 'NM_001835', 'NM_001877', 'NM_001954', 'NM_005214', 'NM_005242', 'NM_005475', 'NM_005561', 'NM_005565', 'ex1', 'ex2', 'NM_003890', 'NM_004106', 'AF029684', 'M28825', 'M32074', 'NM_000139', 'NM_000173', 'NM_000208', 'NM_000316', 'NM_000318', 'NM_000450', 'NM_000539')
myV <- plotVenn(list(g1=g1, g2=g2, g3=g3, g4=g4))
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
```

The last command is repeated on purpose. The result: 
[image: nvennr_vd2]

You can then explore the intersections:

```
> getVennRegion(myV, c('g1', 'g2', 'g4'))
[1] "NM_000139" "NM_000173" "NM_000208" "NM_000316" "NM_000318" "NM_000450" "NM_000539"
```

There is a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) with more information.